# Same line flow suppress comment for imports

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there any way to have a suppress comment in Flow that is in the same line as an import?

```
import Foo from '.bar'
=> throws module not found

// $FlowFixMe
import Foo from '.bar'
=> no error
```

Ideal:

```
import Foo from '.bar' // $FlowFixMe
=> cleaner code
```

Comment: The [suppress comment](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) always looks for an error on the next line so I don't think there is a way to make it inline. You could play around with `suppress_comment` regex, but I doubt you'd get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore all ".bar" extension errors by adding mapper in ".flowconfig" file first and then mock.

```
[options]
 module.name_mapper.extension='bar' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/BarMock.js.flow'
```

project root path -> flow path -> BarMock.js.flow -> file create

```
 // @flow
  declare export default "your bar type"
```